# Fit a rectangle inside a square while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to scale down a rectangular screenshot to fit inside a smaller square. The rectangle is 640x352, and I want to fit it within a 200x200 square, while being as wide as possible (so its long side will be 200 also). And I want to retain its aspect ratio.

I came across this formula on Stack Overflow:

> Given you have two images with sizes (w1, h1) and (w2, h2) and you
>   want to scale the second image to the same area as the first while
>   maintaining the aspect ratio, then
>
> ```
> A = w1 * h1
> new_w2 = sqrt(A * (w2 / h2))
> new_h2 = A / new_w2
> ```

and it seems to be close to what I want, but since it actually creates another rectangle with matching *area*, it doesn't fit inside the square. It actually gives me a new rectangle with sides of 269.679944985 by 148.323969742 (which indeed comes out to 40000, the same as 200x200). I feel like I'm close but, for a programmer, I am really terrible at math. Any ideas will be appreciated.

In fact I'm so bad at math that I don't even know what to tag this. I'll go with trigonometry and edit once someone corrects me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{640}{x}=200=>x=\dfrac{640}{200}=?\quad$ Then $\dfrac{352}x=?$

Comment: That was a real brain fart on my part. Thanks. Hopefully it'll be useful to someone else who's resizing screenshots.